# How to implement multi row select in this ace admin jqgrid table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using [this](http://ace.jeka.by/jqgrid.html) ace admin dynamic table template which uses jqGrid. I managed to load data from database, and perform single row edit and delete operations. However I am not able to do multi row delete even though the template provides multi row select facility. There are no issues with edit,delete queries. The problem is multiple row id's are not getting passed.

```
jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
// code to fetch dynamic JSON data      
editurl: "edit.php",
multiselect: true,
// some other code
});
```

In edit.php file

```
switch ($_POST["oper"]) {
case "add":
    // do mysql insert statement here
break;
case "edit":
    // do mysql update statement here
break;
case "del":
    // do mysql delete statement here
break; }
```

On selecting multiple check-boxes and clicking the delete icon, the following event (which was already present in the template) is fired.

```
  $(t, w).attr({
  title: m.deltitle || "",
  id: e.id || "del_" + v
  }).click(function() {
     if (!$(this).hasClass(k.disabled)) {
     var a;
     o.p.multiselect ? (a = o.p.selarrrow,0 === a.length && (a = null)) : a = o.p.selrow,a ? $.isFunction(m.delfunc) ? m.delfunc.call(o, a) : $(o).jqGrid("delGridRow", a, e) : ($.jgrid.viewModal("#" + n.themodal, {
                                    gbox: "#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID(o.p.id),
                                    jqm: !0
                              }),
    $("#jqg_alrt").focus())
    }
    return !1
 })
```

I have been reading the template's code for hours, but I can hardly understand it since I am a beginner. Please suggest how to do multiple select.

Comment: I suppose that you need just implement correct code in `case "del":` part of your server code (`edit.php`). jqGrid will send **comma separated** list of rowids to the server. Thus you should split the value of `id` parameter, which will be send to `edit.php` and delete separately all the data.

Comment: @Oleg Thank you so much, that worked!!

Comment: You are welcome! I'll post the same information as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you need just implement correct code in `case "del"`: part of your server code (`edit.php`). jqGrid will send **comma separated** list of rowids to the server. Thus you should split the value of id parameter, which will be send to `edit.php` and delete separately all the data.